# Why performance of C++ fseek/fread is times greater than C# FileStream's Seek/Read

Tags: c#, c++, performance, filestream

I'm doing pretty simple test:

1. Have a big file with random binary information with the size of ~6Gb
2. Algorithm makes a loop of "SeekCount" repetitions
3. Each repetition is doing the following:

   - Calculates random offset within the range of file size
   - Seeks to that offset
   - Reads the small block of data

**C#:**

```
    public static void Test()
    {
        string fileName = @"c:\Test\big_data.dat";
        int NumberOfSeeks = 1000;
        int MaxNumberOfBytes = 1;
        long fileLength = new FileInfo(fileName).Length;
        FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read, 65536, FileOptions.RandomAccess);
        Console.WriteLine("Processing file \"{0}\"", fileName);
        Random random = new Random();
        DateTime start = DateTime.Now;
        byte[] byteArray = new byte[MaxNumberOfBytes];

        for (int index = 0; index < NumberOfSeeks; ++index)
        {
            long offset = (long)(random.NextDouble() * (fileLength - MaxNumberOfBytes - 2));
            stream.Seek(offset, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            stream.Read(byteArray, 0, MaxNumberOfBytes);
        }

        Console.WriteLine(
            "Total processing time time {0} ms, speed {1} seeks/sec\r\n",
            DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds, NumberOfSeeks / (DateTime.Now.Subtract(start).TotalMilliseconds / 1000.0));

        stream.Close();
    }
```

Then doing same test in **C++:**

```
void test()
{
     FILE* file = fopen("c:\\Test\\big_data.dat", "rb");

char buf = 0;
__int64 fileSize = 6216672671;//ftell(file);
__int64 pos;

DWORD dwStart = GetTickCount();
for (int i = 0; i < kTimes; ++i)
{
    pos = (rand() % 100) * 0.01 * fileSize;
    _fseeki64(file, pos, SEEK_SET);
    fread((void*)&buf, 1 , 1,file);
}
DWORD dwEnd = GetTickCount() - dwStart;
printf(" - Raw Reading: %d times reading took %d ticks, e.g %d sec. Speed: %d items/sec\n", kTimes, dwEnd, dwEnd / CLOCKS_PER_SEC, kTimes / (dwEnd / CLOCKS_PER_SEC));
fclose(file);
}
```

**Execution times:**

1. C#: 100-200 reads / sec
2. C++: 250 000 reads / sec (250 thousands)

**Question:** why does C++ is thousands times faster than C# on such a trivial operation as file read?

**Additional information:**

1. I played with stream buffers and set them to the same size (4Kb)
2. Disk is de-fragmented (0% fragmentation)
3. OS configuration: Windows 7, NTFS, some latest modern 500Gb HDD (WD if recall correctly), 8 GB RAM (though it is almost not used), 4 Core CPU (utilization is almost zero)

Comment: That's not C++, that C.

Comment: Also, what is the value of `MaxNumberOfBytes`?

Comment: C# is just about 4 times slower than C with all else equal. Sometimes bit more than 4 times. Nothing to do.

Comment: @Öö Tiib: That may be your experience but that factor is extremely context sensitive. In any case the OP is claiming orders of magnitude in difference which must mean he's comparing apples to oranges, somehow.

Comment: Marshalling the data into the CLR is a costly operation.

Comment: `(rand()%100)*0.01` seems suspicious - effectively you're only reading one of 100 offsets of the file which might make use of underlaying caching mechanisms and thus not really reading the chunk from the disk. try using something like `rand() % fileSize` for the code to be more aligned with the C# version.

Comment: The C++ number is messed up.  A disk can only do 100 seeks per second.

Comment: You said the file is 6 GB but you did not say how much memory your box has.  If your box has 8 GB memory, then the entire file would be cached.  If you have 4 GB, then 2/3 is cached.

Comment: Depending on what you really want to do, you might want to look into [memory mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx).

Comment: i think you need to post the entire test programs.  they're not so long.  there are too many variables here.  for example, caching... error in the timer, bug in your code, etc. etc.

Comment: **@thang:** The code is changed to show complete listing.  

**brianbeuning:** The box has 8Gb of memory and file is not loaded into the memory entirely by IO functions.  

**andr:** rand() returns the value from 0 to MAX_RAND, which is at least 32767, (rand()%100)*0.01 is used to normalize the value to become double 0-1

Comment: David, try to change C# random portion to match C - most likely you'll get nearly the same result: repalce `random.NextDouble()` with `(((long)(32767* random.NextDouble()) % 100) * 0.01)`. Also consider using Stopwatch in C# for measurements.

Comment: @David: You missed his point, the C++ code will only read from 100 locations picked randomly, whereas the Java will read from all locations, that's hardly fair.  For the C++, change it to `rand()/double(RAND_MAX)*fileSize` to have the same functionality as the Java

Comment: You're comparing reading `MaxNumberOfBytes` bytes in C# and `one` byte in C. Is it right?

Comment: **@MooingDuck**: you are right, thank you. I'll make some more tests, but it seems like your comment is valid and my code had an error with random.

Comment: **@MooingDuck:** Do you want to post your answer as official answer to the question, so I can give you a credit by choosing as best answer?

Comment: Don't use `random` functions in the programs. Generate a list of random numbers first, then use that list in both programs. I.E. the same numbers for each.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an error in C++ version of the test - the calculation of random offset was limited and thus seek was made only within a short distance, which made C++ results look much better.

Correct code for calculating the offset was suggested by @MooingDuck:

> **rand()/double(RAND_MAX)*fileSize**

With that change performance becomes comparable for both C++ and C# - around 200 reads/sec.

Thanks everyone for contributing.